# Yeaoman Grunt imagemin Fatal error: Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I keep on getting when running `grunt build` even with a clean Yeoman angular build: `yo angular whatever`.

> Warning: Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
>
> Fatal error: Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined

Answer (score 17, accepted):

just update your grunt-contrib-imagemin version.

Ex: `"grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.9.2"`

to

`"grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0"`

it's work for me.

Comment: Yea. There was no version 1 back then I don't think.

Answer (score 8):

I had to downgrade imagemin and it now all works.

```
npm cache clean && npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin@0.9.1
```

Answer (score 3):

I changed in Gruntfile.js this line:

```
src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
```

to this line:

```
src: '[*/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}]'
```

Comment: with this grunt build will work, but no images are minified

Comment: Images are not minified as @Seb said.